# Error when "unzipping" powerpoint file using Archive Utility

Tags: catalina, ms-office

When [using this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091628/how-to-export-movie-from-powerpoint-2010) to extract data from PPTX file I get an error

> Unable to expand archive "test.pptx.zip". It is in an unsupported format

How do I extract video from my PPTX then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it is to either try different unzip utility, such as 7zip, or use terminal: navigate to the folder with your "test.pptx.zip" and run these commands:

```
mkdir test_dir
cd test_dir
unzip ../test.pptx.zip
```

First line creates folder `test_dir` and then moves to that folder. Final command unzips your pptx file into `test_dir` folder